# Array inside JSON received empty

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending a JSON object when submitting a form that contains some primitive types and one array of objects from a browser (JavaScript) to an ASP.NET MVC backend, but the array of objects is deserialized as an empty array (list, actually).

I've checked what's being sent using Chrome's inspector and the JSON goes out with the correct values, so I believe the issue is in the backend.

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(FooViewModel viewModel)
{
    //code
}
```

FooViewModel:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public List<BarViewModel> Bars { get; set; } // <-- What arrives empty, not null

    public int PrimitiveProperty { get; set; }

    public int OtherPrimitiveProperty { get; set; }

    public string LastPrimitiveProperty { get; set; }
}
```

BarViewModel:

```
public class BarViewModel
{
    public long LongProperty{ get; set; }

    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When debugging the controller's action, `Bars` is empty (not null).

And this is what Chrome's inspector shows me:

```
LastPrimitiveProperty: SomeText
PrimitiveProperty: 1
OtherPrimitiveProperty: 9
Bars: [{"LongProperty":274,"StringProperty":"SomeString","BoolProperty":true},{"LongProperty":119,"StringProperty":"SomeString","BoolProperty":false},{"LongProperty":163,"StringProperty":"SomeString","BoolProperty":false}]
```

Comment: Everything seems fine for me

Comment: try adding FromBody to your action FooAction. (FooAction([FromBody]FooViewModel viewModel) )

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction([FromBody]FooViewModel viewModel)
{
   //code
}
```

Try this and it should collect the json object